# How to hide FAB is show in Android

Tags: android

I am using this library `FAB` : **[FABToolbar](https://github.com/fafaldo/FABToolbar)**
I want to hide fab button when **isShow** it, and i want to write this code in **`onBackPressed()`** but this code show me error.

> onBackPress method code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fabToolbar.show()) {
        fabToolbar.hide();
    } else {
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

> but show me this error :

[image]

How can i fix this problem and check **isShow** for this **FAB** ?

Comment: `fabToolbar.show()` is a method for displaying fabToolbar not for checking fabToolbar is showing or not

Comment: You can use "isShown()" to get the visibility.

Comment: there is a method name isShown() for that which will return boolean value. NOT show() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look properly in library [isToolbar()](https://github.com/fafaldo/FABToolbar/blob/master/FABToolbar/library/src/main/java/com/github/fafaldo/fabtoolbar/widget/FABToolbarLayout.java#L460)

`isToolbar()` return true if ToolBar is visible else it will return false

```
public boolean isToolbar() {
    return isToolbar;
}
```

---

#### EDIT

```
if (fabToolbar.isToolbar()) {
        fabToolbar.hide();
    } else 
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Can you send me full code, my mean is send me onBackPress method codes. thanks

Comment: this code just close activity, not hide fab . i need is fab shown first hide this and then close activity

Comment: Thanks my dear friend <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113510/discussion-between-n-j-and-palang).

Answer (score 2):

This library is a `RelativeLayout`, therefore you can use the `public boolean isShown()` method from `View` :

To hide the button if it's shown, and then close the activity, do as follow :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fabToolbar.isToolbar()) {
        fabToolbar.hide();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

However, if you want your back button to behave as
Is Fab showing? If so hide it, otherwise close the activity
Then have the following :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fabToolbar.isToolbar()) {
        fabToolbar.hide();
    } else 
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

EDIT : N J is correct, the library uses `isToolbar()` to store the visibility.

Comment: Thanks, but when hide fab and click on back button. not close the activity! how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to close the activity every time, but hide the Fab if it's showing before?

Comment: See my edit then, which does what you're looking for : if the Fab is showing, then we hide it. Then we close the activity whatever happens

Comment: this code just close activity and not hide fab button!

Comment: Well it does hide the Fab, but since it also closes the activity you probably don't see the fab being hidden. But that's the logic you wanted to achieve (at least from what I understood)

Comment: My last edit shows two different logic, as I couldn't clearly understand what you were trying to achieve. The 2nd logic is "first back : hide Fab, 2nd click close activity"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113504/discussion-between-palang-and-nicolas-simon).

Comment: can yo go to the chat ?

Answer (score 0):

its must be fabToolbar.isShown() and super.onBackPressed() when you use inside

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fabToolbar.isShown()) {
        fabToolbar.hide();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when hide fab and click on back button. not close the activity! how can i fix it?